# Error when try to use twig in slim, Fatal error: TwigView::getEnvironment()

Tags: php, php-5.3, twig, slim

i have a problem when i want to try implementation slim with Twig View.
the error :

```
Fatal error: TwigView::getEnvironment() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/Autoloader.php' (include_path='.:/opt/local/etc/php5') in /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/slim/Slim-Extras/Views/TwigView.php on line 87
```

this is my code

```
require '/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
 17 require '/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/slim/Slim-Extras/Views/TwigView.php';
 18 /*
 19  * initialize slim to use TwigView Handler
 20  */
 21 $app = new Slim(array(
 22       'view'=> new TwigView()
 23 ));
 24 //$app->init(array('view' => 'TwigView'));
 25 $app->get('/',function() use ($app){                                                                                                                                            
 26    $title = "hi there are new twig";
 27    $body = "and this is body maybe you are have idea for this content...:)";
 28    $data = array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body);
 29    $app->view()->setData(array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body));
 30    $app->render('TopPage.html');
 31   // echo "hai you are coll man";
 32 
 33 });
 34 $app->get('/hello/',function(){
 35     echo 'Hello' ;
 36 });
 37 $app->get('/hello/:name',function($name){
 38     echo "yaay...exellent ".$name;
 39 });
 40 $app->run();
```

any suggestion? i don't know why i got error like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm sorry, i'm solve my problem by my self, i found the solution.

Download Twig Example from git

```
git clone git://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
```

and in your slim php file, setting  twig directory example like this code

```
TwigView::$twigDirectory = '/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/slim/Twig/lib/Twig';
 TwigView::$twigExtensions = array(
      'Twig_Extensions_Slim'
  );
```

Comment: Better do: `require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
\Slim\Extras\Views\Twig::$twigDirectory = '../vendor/twig/lib/Twig';
\Slim\Extras\Views\Twig::$twigExtensions = array(
 'Twig_Extensions_Slim',
);`

Comment: @Tim `PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: Slim\\Views\\Twig::$twigDirectory`